# append com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela que abre em um pop up para a pesquisa de material de um cadastro de requisição de material, na pagina (sem ser o pop up) tem uma outra tabela que quando eu adiciono um material que foi selecionado no pop up ele copia as informações do material selecionado na tabela do pop up para a tabela da pagina. O problema é que quando eu adiciono um material por exemplo: aço, ele copia os dados do aço tudo ok, mas se eu faço uma nova pesquisa, exemplo: concreto, quando eu adiciono o concreto, ao invés de fazer o append ele sobrescreve o aço, se eu adiciono dois materiais da mesma pesquisa, ai faz o append corretamente.

```
//Pesquisa os materiais
    function Pesquisar() {
        $('.corpoTbl').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Sip/RCM/ListarMateriais",
            type: "POST",
            data: { nome: $('#Pesquisar').val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (I, item) {
                    $('#tbl').append("<tr class=\"corpoTbl\"> <td class=\"ids\">" + item.ID + "</td><td id=\"nome\">" + item.Nome + "</td><td id=\"unidade\"><center>" + item.Unidade +
                        "</center></td><td> <center><input class=\"qtda\" type=\"text\" value=\"0\" style=\"width: 50px;\" /></center> </td><td> <center><img class=\"icon-plus\" src=\"/Sip/Content/Imagens/add.png\" /></center> </td></tr>")
                })
            }
        });
    }

    //adiciona o item na tabela de listagem
    $('#telaMaterial').on('click', '.icon-plus', function (event) {
        var $botao = $(event.target);
        var $tr = $botao.closest('tr');
        var $qtda = $tr.find('.qtda').val();
        var $id = $tr.find('.ids').text();
        if ($qtda > 0 && $qtda != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Sip/RCM/AddCarrinho",
                type: "POST",
                data: { "qtda": $qtda, "id": $id },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Material Adicionado!");
                    $('#tabelaMaterial').append("<tr class=\"corpoTbl\"> <td class=\"idMat\">" + $id + "</td><td>" + $tr.find('#nome').text() + "</td><td><center>" + $tr.find('#unidade').text() +
                    "</center></td><td class=\"qtd\"><center>" + $qtda + "<center></td><td id=\"excluir\"> <center><img class=\"icon-remove\" src=\"/Sip/Content/Imagens/cancel.png\" /></center> </td></tr>")
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você chama a function `Pesquisar()` a primeira linha é

```
$('.corpoTbl').remove();
```

Que acaba removendo todos `<tr class=\"corpoTbl\">` que você adicionou anteriormente, acredito removendo essa linha vai funcionar corretamente. :)

Comment: Eu coloquei o ID da tabela errada nesse remove e nem percebi, vlw.